Following the Token Extension Program, How do I add a burn function to my token
I followed the youtube torutrial from the solana yt channel(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U1ae2D2jk4), but they don't include how to add the burn function and when I go to the website they don't use the token extension program but, use solana playground instead. For the Token extension program, they use command prompt instead of playground.
Doc used in the video using cmd prompt: https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token
Doc used in the website I think using playground: https://solana.com/developers/courses/tokens-and-nfts/token-program-advanced

You can also use the CLI to burn the tokens:
spl-token create-token
-> Copy MintAddress 
spl-token create-account MintAddress
-> Copy tokenAccount 
spl-token mint MintAddress 1000
spl-token burn tokenAccount 10 

This will create a token, mint 1000 of it and then burn 10
